# Taking email address from twitter using spring social

Tags: twitter, spring-social

It is many answers on web like "Twitter is not giving email address" -- now you can ask their tech support for extended rights for your application (and I get it).
At first, I made all actions with Twitter on client side (on Android, using Twitter SDK by Fabric), so I'm receiving email address like this:

```
bTwitterHidden.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            TwitterSession session = result.data;
            twitterLoginUri = new UriConstructor(getSupportFragmentManager()).makeFullURI("/customer/loginTwitter");
            if (twitterLoginUri != null) {
                TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
                authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<String> result) {
                        try {
                            String email = result.data;
                            //Some actions...
                            }
                        } catch (SignatureException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                            //...
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        //...
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            //...
        }
    });
```

But now i'm trying to get access token on client side, and send it to server part, and get email there. I'm using Spring Social for it (but I don't mind to use something else if someone give me working code). I know how to make connection to Twitter:

```
TransferMessage loginTwitter(@RequestBody String clientToken) {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterTemplate(clientToken);
    //TODO
}
```

But how can I get user's email?

Comment: Read this [Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-twitter/issues/97). Note from Comment: *You also need to regenerate all tokens generated in Twitter. Revoke app permission from your user and try to login again to make sure the token generated includes that permission*. Also check this working [Example](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/commit/920260eef4419e069bd1b4d0bf2810a06d5ba536). PS: This example can be improved.

Comment: Thanks, Sanjay! That helped.